# Bootstrap 4 carousel not sliding when changing route in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I'm fully aware that Bootstrap has Vue-Bootstrap to back it up. But since I'm using a legacy code from my company, It quite took a lot of time to changing it since the website itself using bootstrap 4 as a base. But I got this problem when trying to implement bootstrap 4 `Carousel`. When I refresh the page, the carousel working normally without any problem. But this problem occured when I'm changing a route like for example from `/task` to `/home`. If I refresh in one of the route, the carousel working normally but when I'm trying to change the route the `Carousel will stop working`.

this is my component code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Start Cover Section -->
    <div class="wow fadeIn">
      <div
        id="carousel"
        class="carousel slide carousel-fade"
        data-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="cover-container desktop">
          <h1 class="title">
            <b>{{ titleUpper }}</b> <br />
            <span class="mini-title">{{ titleUnder }}</span>
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="cover-mobile-container mobile">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h1 class="title">
                <b>{{ titleUpper }}</b> <br />
                {{ titleUnder }}
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active img-cover-1"></div>
          <div class="carousel-item img-cover-2"></div>
          <div class="carousel-item img-cover-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Cover Section -->
  </div>
</template>
```

this is my script:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    titleUpper: {
      type: String,
      default: "Company"
    },
    titleUnder: {
      type: String,
      default: "Section"
    }
  },
  name: "Cover",
  data() {
    return {
      message: ""
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

this is my background CSS:

```
.img-cover-1 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-cover-2 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-cover-3 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

so I just wondering Is there any solution for this problem instead changing it to Vue-Bootstrap?